# rnfirebase updatePhOneNumber throw a error com.facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast to java.lang.string

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to update the mobile number using rnfirebase.

```
const p_credential = await firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
    verificationId,
    inputs.code,
)
console.log("3",p_credential) // prints the credential // working 
    
let u_p = await firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(p_credential);

const phone_updated = await firebase.auth().currentUser.then(()=>{
    console.log("Success update phone");
})
```

getting error on passing the credential to the updatePhoneNumber function

the error is
"com.facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast to java.lang.string"

Comment: What type is inputs.code? I'm guessing that's the ReadableNativeMap that should be a string instead.

Comment: that code is otp that actually we are entering manually so am passing it as a string  and the console.log is printing the created credential,  when we pass that credential to await firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(p_credential)  there am geting the error.

Comment: The thing i want is to update the phone number of the user.

Comment: hi bro any help?

Comment: I don't know that firebase code sorry. I guess you need to look at the call stack you're getting with the error and work out what the value is that has the wrong type, and where it's coming from.

Comment: okay ....let me check